# How to send very large objects over socket

Tags: java, sockets, large-data

My system involves sending very large amounts of data and metadata over TCP sockets.  I am sending a single object which contains various metadata, as well as twenty byte arrays.  I've been working on small examples (130kB arrays) so far using ObjectOutputStream enclosing a BufferedOutputStream.  I tried getting up to my goal of 67MB arrays, but ObjectOutputStream can't handle that much data.  I was able to send 1MB arrays, but writeObject() hung up at 2MB.

I've heard that DataOutputStream is faster, but I would rather not have to encode my metadata as bytes and decode on the other side.  Is there a good alternative to be able to send very large objects quickly?

**EDIT:**

I am already using reset() after each write method.  I am currently sending a single SignedObject which encloses my own Message object which encloses the 20 arrays as well as a number of metadata fields.  I would prefer to keep this all packaged since it is so convenient, but I understand that separation may be the only way to go.  That being said, I would still need to make sure that all transmissions are secure.

**UPDATE:**

So I went to lunch, came back, and decided I'd try to figure out whether things were hanging on the send or receive end.  And then it never got hung up.  I could continue to successfully send up to 4MB arrays until I ran out of heap (which is unrelated and just means I need a better computer or more efficient processing).  So I guess the problem went away?  Doesn't mean I don't need a better way of transmitting this though, so I'll take more ideas if people have them.  Also, I'm assuming as soon as I update this, it will stop working again...

Comment: Use quantum physics to sen it instantly? :-)

Or do it the boring way: compression

Comment: Do you really expect the transfer of 60MB of data to happen instantly?  No matter how you do it (unless you can compress or eliminate huge portions of it), it's going to be relatively slow.  That's part of why we don't have computers that boot from the internet and such.

Comment: "Too slow" being it hangs indefinitely.  Edited for clarification

Comment: if your code hung, then you have a bug.  I've used ObjectOutputStream to send GB of data w/out an issue.  while the protocol can be a bit verbose, it _won't_ hang.  as for the verbosity, if you're sending large amounts of data, i doubt the OOS overhead will matter.

Comment: @jtahlborn: If it hangs, then could the problem be on the receive end?

Comment: certainly.  if the receiver stops reading, eventually the socket will block on the sending side.

Comment: a simple speed test would be to first try writing the data to a local file.  that should give you some idea of how fast this should be.

Comment: @jtahlborn If the code hung, the socket send buffer is full, which means the receiver isn't keeping up with the sender, which could be either a coding or speed problem at the receiver *or* just a slower than expected network.

Comment: @EJP - exactly.  i believe i covered all of those in various comments (except maybe the slow network).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a good alternative to be able to send very large objects quickly?

Use ObjectOutputStream with reset() between objects sent.  Unless you only have a few MB of memory (inwhich cas eyou should get more) you won't have a problem.

ObjectOutputStream is pretty slow compared to encoding the bytes yourself, but it can handle the encoding just fine. It's more likely that you network upload speed is your limiting factor. In this example it is sending about 600 Mb/s whereas most braodband connection are around 500 kb/s (about 1000x slower)

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(0);
Socket s = new Socket("localhost", ss.getLocalPort());
final Socket s2 = ss.accept();
ss.close();

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int count = 0;
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        try {
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new InflaterInputStream(s2.getInputStream()));
            while (in.readObject() != null) count++;
            s2.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("Read %,d objects in %.3f seconds%n", count, time / 1e9);
    }
}, "reader").start();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
        new DeflaterOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()));
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[67 * 1000 * 1000];
    oos.writeObject(bytes);
    oos.reset();
}
oos.writeObject(null); // poison pill
oos.close();
s.close();
```

prints

```
Read 20 objects in 21.644 seconds
```

Comment: it sounds like the OP is sending one large object, so reset may not be usable in this context.

Comment: @jtahlborn The OP says that 2 MB objects are failing.  It's hard to see how just 2 MB could be too much.  There would have to hundreds  to cause a problem.